# how to use discord.py to put a custom prescense on a users account?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, apple-music

I want to make a program that shows the current song playing on a users (mine) apple music app on MacOS and display the info in the users' discord presence (not on a bot account), similar to the Spotify integration. However, all of the docs I'm reading for how to use discord.py, it only talks about using it with a bot, and I cannot find how to just use it for the user. I may not be looking in the right place but I'm not sure. Is there a way to just use it with a user, or do you need a bot to use discord.py?

I'm kinda dumb so sorry in advance and please help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a self-bot for this purpose and since it's against Discord's TOS I wouldn't recommend it.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

client.change_presence(
    activity = discord.Activity(
        type = discord.ActivityType.listening,
        song = "I am so screwed!"
    )
)

client.run("YOUR TOKEN")
```

Comment: yeah, i only learned after i posted this that discord.py is only made for bots, and what RPC is for. Thank u very much for the example tho! I'm still new to programming, at least discord stuff so forgive me. Would u happen to be able to recommend any good apis for RPC that would help me out here too?

Answer (score -2):

Do it how you would normally with a bot, but replace the bot's token with your own. Make sure you're using **discord.py** and not a fork, as not all forks support selfbots.

```
client.run("Your Token, not a bots")
```

Comment: Would that be the application ID?